# How to configure alpine for ionos mail using the .pinerc file?

Tags: command-line, configuration, email, smtp, email-client

In using `alpine` I'm composing messages and see:

```
HOST: smtp.foo.bar  ENTER LOGIN NAME [nicholas] :                                                                               
^G Help                                                                                                                             
^C Cancel             Ret Accept
```

then:

```
HOST: smtp.foo.bar  USER: foo@bar.baz  ENTER PASSWORD:                                                     
^G Help                                                                                                                             
^C Cancel             Ret Accept
```

but where are these explicitly set in the `.pinerc` file?

Also, it seem to be picking up the username from the system as above `[nicholas]` so that other users cannot seem to use the `.pinerc` file.  More exactly, the system user name shows in the `sent` field for the e-mail, rather than the name as entered in the `.pinerc`.

This isn't for `gmail` but using `ionos` as:

```
 Account settings for IMAP
Incoming Mail Server Setting    Value
Server address  imap.ionos.com
Port (for SSL)  993
Port (Unsecured)    143
Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) Setting     Value
Server  smtp.ionos.com
Port (for SSL Encryption)   465
Port (TLS/STARTTLS, alternative to SSL)     587
Account settings for POPs
Incoming Mail Server Setting    Value
Server Address  pop.ionos.com
Port (for SSL Encryption)   995
Port (Unsecured)    110
Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) Setting     Value
Server address  smtp.ionos.com
Port (for SSL)  465
Port (TLS/STARTTLS, alternative to SSL)     587

Please note: Activate the SMTP authentication option for the outgoing mail server (SMTP), not the SPA option.
```

which works fine for `thunderbird` but can't quite get working for the `alpine` client.

Answer (score 0):

the inbox seems to be:

```
inbox-path={imap.ionos.com:993/ssl/user=foo@bar.baz}INBOX
```

And:

```
smtp-server=smtp.ionos.com:587/tls/user=foo@bar.baz
```

it seems to work, but I'm not quite sure that's fully correct.