# How do I setup Alpine email client to connect my Gmail account using IMAP? (pine e-mail client)

Tags: command-line, gmail, smtp, imap, email-client

After configuring `alpine` email client for [ionos](https://askubuntu.com/a/1335224/847449) thought I'd try gmail, but can't seem to login.  I'm using `MFA` on my gmail account.

It's simply a [fact](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645740/101935) that `alpine` will no longer work with gmail?

Comment: GMail uses application specific passwords when you have MFA enabled.  You have to generate an app password and *that* is the PW you use for the IMAP login.